# Reload a div element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a data table in my spring mvc project. I need to refresh this table after editing or deleting the data without refreshing the whole page. 
Here is `html` **div** element.

```
<div id="datatable"> </div>
```

I tried it in this way. `$("#datatable").load("butterflyImage #datatable");`
`ButterflyImage` is the name of the `jsp` page. But it didn't work. What is the issue?

When I try `$("#datatable").load("butterflyImage');`
The whole page will appear on within `datatable` **div** element.

Comment: who knows, could be a million things. any errors in you dev console? does the jsp page exist? have you got jquery loaded? has the data changed in the jsp page?

Comment: Yes, data has changed. When I refresh the page manually. I can see changed data

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
$.get("butterflyImage",function(response){
    $("#datatable").html($(response).find("#datatable").html());
});
```

But it's very inefficient and would be better to have the jsp just output the content that you need to refresh.

Comment: Won't this result in a tag with id `#datatable` being nested inside another with the same id?  Shouldn't it be: `$("#datatable").html($(response).find("#datatable").html());`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty true, edited, personally I would not use the approach at all though